# How to dynamically test and build a complex PostgreSQL expression?

Tags: postgresql

I like how many languages let you test expressions in a terminal / shell / REPL before putting them into a code base. Is there a way to try out PostgreSQL expression -- such as a logic expression for a [constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-constraints.html) -- without having to (a) add the constraint to the database or (b) query an existing database? (I'm looking for something minimal.)

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing schema alterations without changing the schema do it inside a transaction:

```
begin;

alter table t add foreign key (osm) references s(i);

insert into t values (3,3);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "t" violates foreign key constraint "t_osm_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (osm)=(3) is not present in table "s".

rollback;
```

If you liked the test result then `commit` in instead of `rollback`

But if it is just an expression just select it:

```
select 1 > 2
select '2012-01-01' < current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Postgres documentation on queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-overview.html), the following is a legal SQL query:

```
SELECT random();
```

Just substitute in your expression of choice.